# Is Xcode or Android SDK is better than Unity3d to developp an app with battery life in mind?

Tags: android, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, battery

Maybe to reformulate the question more: is the overhead of the default `Unity3D` layer is a big battery consumption?

Imagine an equivalent app developed with `Xcode/AndroidSDK vs Unity`. The app could be a shoot them up with a app-style UI `(eg: material design)`, and using the GPS **(why not ?)**. Let say UI and games graphics will both use Metal (or equivalent on Android if it exists)

Is the delta consumption will be more close to `90%` or `10%` ?

Comment: if battery consumption is important to you better use native, creating with unity3d in even the best times have a lot overhead beside unity3d is more suitable for games creating an application with it may take some flexibility of a native code away from you. and remember a unity3d empty android app is nearly 12MB it's just for a unity player without any scene.

Comment: Have you an idea of the % of consumption Unity 3D come with ?

Comment: I can't give you a calculated percentage, but i think it would be more than 50 present.you'll be amazed how thirsty unity3d gets when your scene became a little complex.most of it because unity optimized for games and trying to keep 30 (or up to 60 based on configuration) fps completely steady,but you don't need that much in a application specially if you don't use animations.

Comment: Wahou... 50%! O_O ok I need to seriously think about it.
Guys, any other opinions ?

Comment: off course in fact recently i wrote an application with unity3d it became very good looking because of freedom in styling and unity helped to publish that application for android,ios and windows phone but it's a small app without any background services and nothing vastly complex. if you planning to create something BIG i highly recommend you to go native.

Comment: Indeed my app will be 'big'. By big I mean there will be multiple contexts. For example a city building context (like clash of clan) and a item list context (like WoW Armory).
This context will never be loaded at same time. So the background execution, even it is a big app, could be similar at yours.
So have you notice any battery drop or overheat in your "simple" app ?

Comment: So i think it's better for you to try some of complex games that created by unity3d and measure their work yourself, and keep in mind although unity3d have these weakness but it have very powerful API that helps you either.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sinuously consider unity3d pro and cons and compare them to what you want from it i talked about it with you in comments but it's best to download some of unity3d created games and try them yourself
and there is a complete discussion about advantage and disadvantage of using unity [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8118/what-are-the-pro-cons-of-unity3d-as-a-choice-to-make-games)

Comment: I don't worry for the complex app. I worry about the simple ones.
A good exemple is to take [Wow Armory](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/world-warcraft-mobile-armory/id321057000?mt=8)
It seems simple to me. In your opinion, would be there a huge difference of consumption in a native version vs a Unity one ?

Comment: IF you creating a `Game` i think you better use Unity3d.